# how to transfer a variable from a server to a client. python

Tags: python-2.7, variables, client-server, transfer

So I am really new to server and client code with python and I am doing this project from this book which asks me to do a couple of things. One of them is to transfer all the files so that the client can see them clearly. Here is the code.

Server:

```
import socket
from PIL import ImageGrab
import sys 
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\Home\Documents\python\new_project')
import pyperclip
import shutil
import glob
import subprocess

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12346
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind((host, port))
Server_online = True

while Server_online:
server_socket.listen(2)

client_socket, client_addr = server_socket.accept()
client_name = client_socket.recv(1024)

if client_name == "Screen Shot":
    im = ImageGrab.grab()
    f = open('C:\Users\Home\Documents\screen.txt')
    i = int(f.read())
    f.close()
    im.save(r"C:\Users\Home\Documents\python\new_project\screen" + str(i) +'.jpg' )
    i = i + 1
    f = open('C:\Users\Home\Documents\screen.txt', 'w')
    f.write(str(i))
    f.close()
    client_socket.send("Picture taken")

elif client_name == "Copy":
    while 1:
        try:
            data = client_socket.recv(1024)
            Copied = pyperclip.copy(data)
            client_socket.send("text copied.")
            break
        except:
            client_socket.send("Failed to copy")

elif client_name == "Paste":
    pasting = pyperclip.paste()

elif client_name == "Show files":
    while 1:
        files = client_socket.recv(1024)
        files_list = glob.glob("C\\Users\\Home\\Documents\\" + files + "\\*.*")
        client_socket.send(**files_list**)
        break
elif client_name == "Exit":
    client_socket.sendall("Exting server...")
    client_socket.close()







 client_socket.close()
 server_socket.close()
```

Client:

```
 import socket
 import time
 import glob
 host = socket.gethostname()
 port = 12346

 client_socket = socket.socket()
 client_socket.connect((host, port))
 client_connected = True
 while client_connected:
        print '''Pick What you want to do.(Screen Shot, Copy, Paste, 
Show files, Open files, Copy files, Exit )'''
request = raw_input()
if request == "Screen Shot":
    print "Screen shot in 5 seconds"
    for i in range(5,0,-1):
        print i
        time.sleep(1)
    client_socket.send("Screen Shot")
    print client_socket.recv(1024)

elif request == "Copy":
    client_socket.send("Copy")
    print "what do u want to be copied:"
    Copied = raw_input()
    client_socket.send(Copied)
    print client_socket.recv(1024)

elif request == "Exit":
    client_socket.send("Exit")
    print client_socket.recv(1024)
    break

elif request == "Paste":
    client_socket.send("Paste")

elif request == "Show files":
    client_socket.send("Show files")
    print "What files do you want to send?"
    files = raw_input()
    client_socket.send(files)
    outcome = client_socket.recv(1024)
    try:
        for files in outcome:
            print files
    except:
        print "no outcome"





else:
    print "Not one of the requests. Enter again."







client_socket.close()
```

So as you can see it is really easy  stuff but what i am stuck on is how to transfer the variable in the "Show files" (server) part where the server sends the client a list of the listed files. (its bloded).
If you can help me out that would be great I have been stuck on this for weeks

Answer (score 0):

Well this is old. I solved this problem later on.
all you need to do is this (better to do it with the struct library):

on the server:

```py
file_list = '\n'.join(file_list)
files_list_len = len(files_list)
client_name.send(files_list_len)
client_name.send(file_list)
```

client side:

```py
recv_size = client_socket.recv(4)
files = client_socket.recv(recv_size).split("\n")
```